# How to prevent button text change?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two problems:

1.I have a button called "enable" once clicked it  becomes disable for which i have used "onclick".In that button itself i have used "onclientclick" to validate the text box that is present(alerts if blank textbox on clicking enable which i have used javascript).The problem is every time it gives alert the page loads and the button text changes from enable to disable even with out clicking

2.I have multiple button which i want chnge from enable to disable on clicking. Is there is possible to have a common code in the back end

```
 Protected Sub cyoeno_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cyoeno.Click


    If cyoeno.Text = "Enable" Then
        cyoeno.Text = "Disable"
    Else
        cyoeno.Text = "Enable"

    End If

End Sub
```

Button

```
 <asp:Button ID="cyoeno"  OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="cyoeno_Click"   runat="server" Text="Enable" />
```

Javascript

```
 function validate(cyclenumber)
  {


       var cycle_1_enddate = document.getElementById('<%=txtEndDate.ClientId%>').value;
       var cycle_1_startdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientId%>').value;

       validatecommon(cycle_1_enddate,cycle_1_startdate);

           }

    function validatecommon(cal1,cal2) {


        if (cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
            return true;
        }
        if (cal1 == '') {
            alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
            return true;
        }
        if (cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
            return true;
        }

        if (cal1 != '' || cal2 != '')
         {
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return true;
            }

             }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide us code of JavaScript function validate.I think problem is in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no expert in either JavaScript or asp.net but you can create handles to handle the click event of several buttons which would look something like this;

```
Private Sub MultipleButtonClick(ByVal sender AS Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.click 'etc

    Dim btn as Button = DirectCast (sender,Button)
    If btn.Text = "Enable" Then
        btn.Text = "Disable"
    Else
        btn.Text = "Enable"
    End If
End Sub
```

There is an assumption here that all of the buttons have the same text.  If not then you could still use the same principle but you would need to use a select statement as well;

```
Private Sub MultipleButtonClick(ByVal sender AS Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.click 'etc

    Dim btn as Button = DirectCast (sender,Button)

    Select Case btn.name

        Case "First name"
                'do stuff here
        Case "Second Name"
                'do stuff here
        Case Else
            Exit Select

    End Select

    End If
End Sub
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending duplicate click signals, that's why your function executes twice even if you only clicked once.

first signal is:

```
Handles cyoeno.Click
```

the duplicate signal is:

```
OnClick="cyoeno_Click"
```

What you basically need to do is to remove one of the two. It's either you go with Handles or you go with OnClick. Not both.

Comment: :Even after doing what u said,it does not work .when "onclientclick" it validates if blank textbox is there it gives alert,once i click ok in the alert box it loads again then button text changes again

Comment: Hi, yes, my bad. As @sagar-shirke answered, your problem is the return values you use for the validation javascript function. An "error" should return a false value. That will prevent a postback if the validation returns false.

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier problem is in javascript.You are returning true every where but if there is any validation problem then your fucntion should return false.
Because if that function return false then postback event will not occur if it is true then it will directly go to the server.

In short use return false to avoid page loads.

Also, if this is your actual code then I am not sure why you are changing text of the button instead of that ideally you should use `cyoeno.Enabled = true;` and `cyoeno.Enabled = false;`

For your second question below method may help you ( it is in C# but you can use logic of it)

```
public void ToggleEnableDisable(Button btn)
{
    if (btn.Enabled)

    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

While calling it use

```
ToggleEnableDisable(cyoeno);
```

Comment: I tried it... does not work .I am not trying to disable it

Comment: OK..Is it possible to provide what code you have tried which is not working..may be few modifications in it will start running the code.